# Отладка Google Play Service из Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, android-service

Пытаюсь разобраться с Google Play для Android-приложений (не Unity). Столкнулся с проблемой подключения к сервисам.

На данный момент, имеется стандартный пример из  https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples - ButtonClicker. Всё собрано, загружено и опубликовано. Если загрузить приложение с маркета - оно работает как и должно.

Проблема в том, что если запускать приложение из AndroidStudio, вход в Google Play начинается, но обрывается и показывает сообщение:

> Failed to sign in. Please check your network connection and try again

И в логах сообщение:

> onActivityResult with requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN, responseCode=10002,
>   ...

Повторюсь, если запускать то же самое приложение из маркета - всё работает нормально. Код идентичен, а значит по всей видимости, дело окружении.

Полагаю, где-то я упустил какие-то тонкости настройки среды разработки, или телефона, или предоставления прав каких-нибудь. Но никак не могу понять что именно не так.

Answer (score 2):

Как обычно, 3 дня бьёшься над проблемой, и как только задаёшь вопрос на форум, сам же находишь решение.

В Google Play Console, в связанных приложениях добавил ещё одно с таким же пакетом, но с SHA1 от debug-apk. Заработало.

Но появилось два вытекающих вопроса:
1. Правильно ли я вообще сделал или же эта проблема решается как-то иначе?
2. Это получается, что если работает одновременно несколько разработчиков, их всех нужно добавлять в консоль?

Comment: Всё правильно. Надо указывать всё использующиеся ключи. Разным разработчикам можно выдать одинаковые дебажные ключи